# Chromedriver Devtools port number error

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, circleci-2.0

I'm getting the following error while trying to run tests using capybara, selenium and chromedriver-helper. The tests run fine locally on a mac using the same version of chromedriver. I've tried setting the remote debugging port explicitly in my spec_helper, but apparently this is ignored as chromedriver uses a random remote debugging port.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
        unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <37329> were in an unexpected format
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.4.0-127-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: How did you fix the issue? I'm having the same issue. Test works fine locally and failed on remote machine.

Comment: I'm in touch with Circle CI support at the moment about the issue but haven't been able to fix it. Have you tried updating Chrome on your remote machine as suggested by stebooks?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same.

Comment: We updated our Ruby Version and Circle CI docker image. This seems to have updated Chrome. We're still having issues, this issue doesn't occur any more though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same problem, I had to upgrade Chrome to the latest release and it fixed it.

Comment: Was using a docker image for the same sort of thing ..
upgraded to FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.13.0 and it now worked.