# chromium vs chromium-browser in the context of running Selenium tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, debian, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to run some Selenium tests in Docker. I moved from `ubuntu:bionic` to `bitnami:jessie` and I found that `chromium-browser` is available in `bionic` and `chromium` is available in `jessie`.

what is the difference between these two packages? if i install `chromium`, then I get following error when running Protractor tests.

```
[05:03:38] E/launcher - unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <45289> were in an unexpected format
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)
[05:03:38] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <45289> were in an unexpected format
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/root/testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/root/testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)                                                                                                                    
    at doSend.then.response (/root/testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)                                                                                                                  
    at <anonymous>                                                                                                                                                                                              
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)                                                                                                                                              
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()               
    at Function.createSession (/root/testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/root/testing/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/root/testing/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/root/testing/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/root/testing/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
```

Comment: I highly recommend to use Solenoid tool https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid . It's easy and solid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is your chromium version?

Here you can see similar problem: [Chromedriver Devtools port number error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854859/chromedriver-devtools-port-number-error)

Right now you are using `chromedriver 2.46.628388`. It supports chrome v71-v73 (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

If your chromedriver is older:

a) update it or,

b) downgrade chromedriver

Comment: Chromium is the open source artifact on top of which Google Chrome is built right? Okay i get the following `# chromium-browser --version, Chromium 71.0.3578.98 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04`; `# chromium --version, Chromium 57.0.2987.98 Built on 8.7, running on Debian 8.11`. so it appears `chromium` package from `jessie` is an older Chromium and requires older Chrome web-driver? I have to find a way to install `chromium-browser` on `jessie` so that I test with the latest version of `chromium`? Do you what is the reliable to install latest version of `Chromium` in `jessie`?

Comment: it appears the `jessie` Debian release I used comes up with an old version of Chromium. I updated the Docker image to use base `bitnami/minideb:stretch` and that pulled in v71 of Chromium.

Comment: I want to know the difference between these two packages, although this answer may solve OP's underlying problem, directly answering this question will serve a broader audience in the future.