# python selenium no launch error: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <62045> were in an unexpected format

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have read many answers and tried adding options and binary location but to no avail. (I have many chrome profiles, I created a new chrome profile and identified it as profile 8.) I downloaded chromedriver last night so assume that is up to date and my chrome is up to date.

Error:
*selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Devtools port number file contents <62045> were in an unexpected format*

MY CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_driver_path = "C:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 8")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)


driver.get(url="https://www.google.com")

driver.quit()
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:
I want to successfully launch chrome and practice with selenium :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromedriver Devtools port number error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854859/chromedriver-devtools-port-number-error)

Comment: Use the compatible chromedriver

Comment: I have tried two verions of chromedriver. (My chrome says: "Google Chrome is up to date
Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)" and I have tried chromedriver "ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107" and "ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.15" to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me, I think that my binary location was wrong, it was not pointing to the path of Program Files.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_driver_path = r"C:\Development\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)


driver.get(url="https://www.bbc.co.uk")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```